# Сделать на время зависимые checkbox

Tags: delphi

Есть 40 штук CheckBox, при установки галочек, на некоторые checkbox, могут происходить одни и теже действия.
Но появляются варианты, когда при установки галочки в одном checkbox нужно снимать галочки со всех остальных checkbox.
И checkbox’ы в программе еще будут появлятся…
**Вопрос**:
Есть ли вариант не писать в каждом таком вариянте событие `checkbox.onclick` код для снятия галочек для всех остальных checkbox’ов.
Например какую-то процедуру, в которую при поступлении определенного названия checkbox, будут сниматься галочки с других checkbox?

Например:

```
procedure TForm1.false_ch(ACheckBox: TCheckBox);
var
  LEvent: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  if CheckBox1 <> ACheckBox then
  begin
    LEvent := CheckBox1.OnClick;
    CheckBox1.OnClick := nil;
    CheckBox1.Checked := false;
    CheckBox1.OnClick := LEvent;
  end;

  if CheckBox2 <> ACheckBox then
  begin
    LEvent := CheckBox2.OnClick;
    CheckBox2.OnClick := nil;
    CheckBox2.Checked := false;
    CheckBox2.OnClick := LEvent;
  end;


 if CheckBox3 <> ACheckBox then
 begin
   LEvent := CheckBox3.OnClick;
   CheckBox3.OnClick := nil;
   CheckBox3.Checked := false;
    CheckBox3.OnClick := LEvent;
 end;
...
  if CheckBox40 <> ACheckBox then
  begin
    LEvent := CheckBox40.OnClick;
    CheckBox40.OnClick := nil;
    CheckBox40.Checked := false;
    CheckBox40.OnClick := LEvent;
  end;
end;
```

Но данный у меня почему-то такое впечатление, что код будет работать **не** совсем корректно.

Comment: прям таки со всех остальных?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, лучше будет все-таки создать процедуру снятия галочек с определенных(списка) чекбоксов, т.е. что-то наподобие

```
procedure RemoveChecked(pCheckBoxList: array of TCheckBox);
var
  CurCB: TCheckBox;
  LEvent: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  for CurCB in pCheckBoxList do
  begin
    LEvent := CurCB.OnClick; // т.е. если реально нужно, чтобы обработчик не срабатывал
    if not CurCB.Checked then
      Continue;
    CurCB.OnClick := nil;
    CurCB.Checked := false;
    CurCB.OnClick := LEvent;
  end;
end;
```

Ну и далее уже для определенных Чекбоксов, при установке галочки в которых, нужно снимать галочку в остальных вызывать указанный метод со списком чекбоксов, с колторых нужно снять галочки. Тут я опускаю вопрос целесообразности и смысла зачем автору надо такое.

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо снять прям таки со всех чекбоксов, тогда можно сделать так:

```
for I := 0 to Form1.ComponentCount-1 do
  begin
    if (Form1.Components[i] is tCheckBox) and (Form1.Components[i].Name <> 'CheckName')
      then TCheckBox(Form1.Components[i]).Checked:= false;
  end;
```

Comment: Вместо `Name` можно назначить всем checkbox один обработчик, и писать проверку на `Form1.Components[i]<>Sender`

Comment: @nick_n_a Очень сомневаюсь что на всех 40ка чекбоксах необходим один обработчик) да и то что необходимо ВСЕ остальные чекать тоже

Comment: В чем беда? 40 штук выделил мышкой с shift-ом или ctrl, двойной клик на OnChange - и всё ок. По крайней мере я так делал.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я не говорю о проблеме "поставить обработчик на 100500 компонентов" я говорю о целесообразности это действа!